# MySQL Query to return list of associated duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently working on a project where I am trying to assign costs to applications rather than servers.

An application can have many servers, and a server can house many applications.

All the data is stored in one database.

```
AppID 
AppName
Server
```

I have run a query to find how many servers each app has, but I need the query to return the list of associated servers as well as the number of them.

The sql query shows how many times a server appears in the table, ie it appears every time an application uses that server.

Does anybody know how can I return the servers associated with each application?

[image: SQL Query result[1]]

Comment: Please post your table structure, and also show some sample data.

Comment: You need to provide relevant table structures. Query you used. Sample data and expected output

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please [edit] your question and add a bit more information. Please gives us some example data and an expected output. Please also let us know what query you've tried already yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a job for [GROUP_CONCAT().](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Try this:

```
  SELECT AppID, AppName, 
         COUNT(*) Number_of_Servers,
         GROUP_CONCAT(Server) Servers
   GROUP BY AppID, AppName
```

Be careful, though: the last column of the result set is a (denormalized)